# Opening a file with a name error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to build a function that asks the user to input the name of a file, opens the file, reads its contents, prints the contents of the file on the screen, and closes the file. If no such file exists, it's okay if the script crashes.  When I run the function, it gives me: NameError: name 'myInput' is not defined, and I'm not sure how to fix it.

Here is what I have so far:

`print(input('Please enter the name of a file that you want to open.' + myInput))
with open(r"C:\Python32\getty.txt", 'r') as infile:
    data = infile.read()
    print(data)`

Help if you can..

Comment: Have you tried instead of `input` use `raw_input`?

Comment: where is  myInput defined?

Comment: raw input didnt work.  and maybe i need to define myInput, but i dont know how to...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`myInput` is an undefined variable, and I can't fathom what you had in mind by using it.

Maybe where you show the code...:

```
print(input('Please enter the name of a file that you want to open.' + myInput))
with open(r"C:\Python32\getty.txt", 'r') as infile:
```

you actually meant something very different, e.g like...:

```
myInput = input('Please enter the name of a file that you want to open.')
with open(myInput, 'r') as infile:
```

...?

Answer (score 1):

In your first line, you have:

```
print(input('Please enter the name of a file that you want to open.' + myInput))
```

do you have `myInput` defined? You need to define it. If you don't have it defined before that line, your script will crash.

This can be gleaned from your helpful error message:

> NameError: name 'myInput' is not defined

Which means that the variable `myInput` is not defined, so the compiler doesn't know what to put there.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this would solve your problem

```
fileName = raw_input("Please enter the name of a file that you want to open. ")
fileObject = open(fileName, "r")
fileText = fileObject.read()
print(fileText)
```